# compiler warnings "differ in signedness"

Tags: c

compiler warnings "differ in signedness"

```
comm.c: In function ‘new_descriptor’:
comm.c:1017: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 3 of ‘accept’ differ in signedness
comm.c: In function ‘get_ident’:
comm.c:4043: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 3 of ‘getsockname’ differ in signedness
comm.c:4044: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 3 of ‘getpeername’ differ in signedness

void new_descriptor(int control)
{
static DESCRIPTOR_DATA d_zero;
DESCRIPTOR_DATA *dnew;
struct sockaddr_in sock;
BAN_DATA *pban;
char buf[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
int desc;
int size;
int addr;
int hostcount;
DESCRIPTOR_DATA *d;

NORESOLVE_DATA *pnoresolve;
bool doresolve;

size = sizeof(sock);
if ((desc = accept(control, (struct sockaddr *) &sock, &size)) < 0) {
    perror("New_descriptor: accept");
    return;
}
```

And

```
char *get_ident(int desc, u_long ip)
 {
struct sockaddr_in us;
struct sockaddr_in them;
static char uid[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
char buf[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
int id;
int size;

strcpy(uid, "(unknown)");

if ((id = start_socket(ip, IDENT_PORT)) < 0)
    return uid;

size = sizeof(us);

if (getsockname(desc, (struct sockaddr *) &us, &size)
    || getpeername(desc, (struct sockaddr *) &them, &size)) {
    CLOSE(id);
    return uid;
}

sprintf(buf, "%u, %u\n", ntohs(them.sin_port), ntohs(us.sin_port));

WRITE(id, buf, strlen(buf) + 1);

memset(buf, '\0', sizeof(buf));

READ(id, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);

if (sscanf(buf, "%*d , %*d : USERID : %*s : %[^\r\n]s", uid) != 1)
    strcpy(uid, "(unknown)");

if (!strcmp(uid, "0"))
    strcpy(uid, "root");

CLOSE(id);
return uid;
}
#endif
```

Comment: The nonchalance of people who ask this kind of questions always amazes me.

Comment: It appears that parameter should be a ` socklen_t*` which is unsigned.

Answer (score 6):

You are using `int size;`, You should not use `int` data type for 3rd argument of `accept`.

Syntax of `accept` is-

`int accept(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);` // Note the 3rd argument

So You should use `socklen_t` data type. Try to declare `size` as a `socklen_t` variable and try-

```
socklen_t size; //like this
```